# PostGIS - st_intersects: WHERE vs INNER JOIN

Tags: postgis, postgresql

In PostgreSQL/PostGIS, when running an intersection between 2 geometries, what the difference between these two syntaxes ?

```
-- Method 1
SELECT
a.id
b.id
FROM a, b
WHERE st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom)

-- Method 2
SELECT
a.id,
b.id
FROM a
INNER JOIN b ON st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
```

In real conditions, first method is longer to execute than second for the same result. Instinctively I would have believed the opposite because the first had one condition, how to explain this ?

An `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT` with the unrolled detail did not enlighten me more (here is an example with real tables, the names do not match the example above).

Method 1
[image: where]

Method 2
[image: inner_join]

I'm using PostgreSQL 13.2 and PostGIS 3.1.1.

Comment: The title is somewhat misleading. This isn't about *syntax* as much as it is about query organization. You should include the EXPLAIN plans for the two queries.

Comment: Ok, I edit it to be more relevant.

Comment: So the two syntax are the same (as the query plan said), no writing recommendations ?

Comment: inner join is just syntactic sugar sprinkled over the old style from a,b where..

Comment: My comment just got deleted for whatever reasons...my point had been that the query plan got cached after the first run and reused, thus the faster execution. The planner is free to restructure and inline statements like `JOIN`s and filters, and the finally executed query is likely identical in both cases.

Comment: apparently you deleted it @geozelot

Comment: @IanTurton oh I wasn't trying to imply that you moderators have sth. to do with it, I blame technology. I did not delete it by intention, at least.

Comment: I just went to check who had deleted it and saw it was you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a INNER JOIN b ON is the same as a JOIN b ON, which is the same as SELECT FROM a,b WHERE.  Your 2 queries are functionally identical.

```
...FROM a,b WHERE st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom)
```

is the same as

```
...FROM a INNER JOIN b ON st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom)
```

is the same as

```
...FROM a JOIN b ON st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom)
```

Comment: why not the same with a left join ?

Comment: @CristiánVargasAcevedo  left join implies an OUTER join, which is different.  It keeps all the rows from the left table including the rows that don't match the join condition.  An inner join only keeps the rows that match the join condition. https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-joins/

Comment: In a test for both cases on spark sql with sedona i get same results....Note In left case add a condition for right table id is not null

Comment: @CristiánVargasAcevedo it's not the same result if you have to add another condition.  It's a different join type